# How do I get to an AzureAD group members from a SharePoint LoginName using the graph?

Tags: spfx, microsoft-graph, office-graph, azure-ad-graph-api, sharepint

I am trying to use the graph to find all users in a SharePoint group on O365. The SharePoint Group contains  Azure AD groups. The LoginName for one of these Azure AD groups within a SharePoint group looks like this:

`c:0-.f|rolemanager|s-1-5-21-1663639147-559416195-7125487034-53164323`

How do I take that LoginName, that represents and Azure AD group and find its members using the graph?

I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx?PageIndex=2) link which explains how the Login names are formed (the above is a claim for a role with a string value with an AuthMode of forms based Autentication), but that does not help. The LoginName seems to represent a SID.

How do I find that Sid in Azure AD using the graph? I Can find the group using its displayName using `v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'The Name of the group'&$expand=members` but that does not help because I have Unified groups and AD groups with the same displayName.

When I run that query to get the group by displayName  the result does not have a SID. It does have an `onPremisesSecurityIdentifier` field, but the value in that field does not equal the SID that is shown in the LoginName value in the SharePoint group.

How do I get to an AzureAD group members from a SharePoint LoginName using the graph?